# Toast location does not update if that toast is already showing

Tags: android, location, toast, gravity

My question, in particular, is in reference to the refreshing of toasts that have already been created.

For example i have a toast that has been created:

```
Toast myToast;

// ...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

And i update it differently upon two actions:

```
if (answerGiven != correctAnswer) {
    myToast.setText("Wrong");


        View view = myToast.getView();
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        text.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        text.setTextSize(32);

    myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
} else {

        View view = myToast.getView();
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        text.setTextSize(32);

   myToast.setText("+" + bonus);

   myToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 20, 20);
}

myToast.show();
```

Both actions work fine! BUT if i tap quickly on the screen and activate the second action BEFORE the toast has disappeared the gravity is not changed even though the message updates.

For example: if i choose the wrong answer, and the "wrong" message shows in the middle of the screen:

[image]

and then i immediately choose the write answer the bonus message appears in the middle of the screen (even though i tell it to set `setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 20, 20);`)

[image]

(note: if i wait until the "Wrong" message disappears and then click the correct answer the bonus message shows in the top left corner as expected)

What i want it to do is to always put the bonus message at the top left. Even if the user clicks to fast. So i am asking: Is there a way that the previous toast can be cancelled so the new message is shown in the correct location. Or is there something i should do (such as refresh my activity) so that the message displays in the correct location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a below sample code and that's working.Please have a look at that

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button btnAddData;
private TextView tv;
private EditText et;
private boolean check;
Toast myToast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    btnAddData = findViewById(R.id.btn_add_record);

    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (check) {
                if (myToast.getView().isShown())
                    myToast.cancel();
                check = false;
                myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                myToast.show();
            } else {
                if (myToast.getView().isShown())
                    myToast.cancel();
                check = true;
                myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                myToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT, 20, 20);
                myToast.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You need to make a button in xml and test that and let me know if you are facing any problem. Further you can adjust according to your need.

Comment: I am glad that helped :) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

You should cancel the current toast before showing new toast message.

```
if (myToast != null) {
    myToast.cancel();
}

// your code ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should Use

[**`Toast.cancel()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#Toast(android.content.Context))

> Close the `view` if it's showing, or don't show it if it isn't showing yet. You do not normally have to call this. Normally `view` will disappear on its own after the appropriate duration.

Try this

```
if (myToast!= null) {
    myToast.cancel();
}
if (answerGiven != correctAnswer) {

    myToast.setText("Wrong");

    myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
} else {


   myToast.setText("+" + bonus);

   myToast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, unfortunately now the toast does not show at all???

Comment: Hmm... still not showing at all. The rest of my code has nothing to do with the toast but perhaps there is some other problem. Do you have any ideas about what could make the toast not appear again after being cancelled? (updated post with more code)

Comment: I figured out the problem, after `Toast.cancel()`  the toast must be recreated. I was using `Toast.setText()` but when i changed the code to `Toast.makeText()` then it worked! Thank you for the help!